# Override gutter width Susy 2

Tags: css, susy, susy-sass

I'm trying to override the gutter width in Susy 2 but can't get it to work as required. My standard set up for the site is as follows which is fine.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: .5,
  gutter-position: after,
);
```

I have an image gallery where I want the spacing between blocks to be much less. I can override the gutter width using (gutter-override: 0.1) however this doesn't effect the width of the blocks. The widths of the blocks are still as if the gutter is .5.

Is it possible to change the gutter for a certain block of content (my gallery) so that the gutter can be a lot smaller and the width of the blocks will reflect this?

Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - `gutter-override` exists specifically for the case where you *don't want to change the grid math*, only override the gutter output. But you can change the math any time you want by setting `gutters` or using the [grid shorthand](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/shorthand/#term-grid):

`gallery(3 (gutters: 0.1))`

or

`gallery(3 of 12 0.1)`

Comment: Hi Miriam, thanks. I've added this is which has overwritten the gutter and changed the widths accordingly. How can I ensure that the margin-bottom i'm adding remains consistent with this overwrite? I was using margin-bottom: gutter(); which doesn't pull in the new gutter

Comment: You can either add the same clarification to the `gutter` function (e.g. `gutter(3 of 12 0.1)`, or you can wrap the entire block of code in a mixin that changes your defaults: `@include with-layout(12 0.1) { /* both your gallery and gutter */ }`. Anything nested inside the `with-layout` mixin will use the grid settings you pass into it. Then you can remove them from the gallery and gutter calls.